# Flutter - dart:convert json decode performance

Tags: json, flutter, decode

We are trying to decode a large json string (~200MB) from web api, the dart:convert json decode performance are really bad. We have using `compute` so it wont affect the UI but the long loading time are blocking the users.

Any other better json decode library in dart?

Comment: no library will help you if you have to parse that huge amount of data, you really need `compute()` function or direct `Isolate` use

Comment: @pskink Does it make sense to do jsonDecode with Isolate if the message passing between isolates is encoding into binary data and back again?

Comment: @SergeyLobanov https://api.dartlang.org/stable/dart-isolate/Isolate/exit.html read the last paragraph

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this article from Andrea : https://codewithandrea.com/articles/parse-large-json-dart-isolates/

By using compute() we can move our parsing code to the worker isolate and get all the performance benefits we want.